# Spring JPA/Hibernate EmptyInterceptor not injecting Entitymanager/Spring beans with JBoss Server

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jboss7.x, tomcat8

With the following configuarations, my code for audit log is working fine on tomcat8 server but when I tried to deploy the same on JBoss 7, It gives the BeanCreationException .
What am I missing. Please help.
Thanks.

my persistence.xml is

```
enter code<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="MyPersistentUnit">

    <!-- JPA Entity classes are configured here -->
    <class>com.hexaview.wealthnewsmate.daotier.models</class>        

    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>

    <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor"  value="com.hexaview.wealthnewsmate.biztier.services.auditlog.AuditTableServiceImpl" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and applicationContext.xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db-info.properties"
        order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:email-info.properties"
        order="2" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:currency-pair-info.properties"
        order="3" ignore-unresolvable="true" />


    <!-- Declare the Interceptor -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
            p:paramName="locale" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <!-- Declare the Resolver -->
    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>authentication-messages_en_US</value>
                <value>messages_en_US</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />

    </bean>

    <!-- JPA config start here -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.hexaview.wealthnewsmate.daotier.repo" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}" />
        <property name="url" value="${spring.datasource.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${spring.datasource.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${spring.datasource.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="${spring.datasource.showSQLs}" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="${spring.datasource.generateDDL}" />
        <property name="database" value="${spring.datasource.type}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="auditInterceptor" class="com.hexaview.wealthnewsmate.biztier.services.auditlog.AuditTableServiceImpl" /> -->

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
         class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
         p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath*:persistence.xml"
         p:persistenceUnitName="MyPersistentUnit">


        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.hexaview.wealthnewsmate.daotier.models"/>
        <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes -->
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
         </property>               

    </bean>

     <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
     </bean>

     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- <bean id="controllerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="urlMap">
            <util:map>
                <entry key="index" value-ref="filenameViewController" />
                <entry key="demo" value-ref="filenameViewController" />
            </util:map>
        </property>
    </bean> -->
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${email.host}" />
        <property name="port" value="${email.port}" />
        <property name="username" value="${email.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${email.password}" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
            <!-- <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">smtp.mail.yahoo.com</prop>-->
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.enable">true</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And detailed execption trace is this

```
enter code18:56:43,054 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'financeNewsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.hexaview.framework.webtier.helpers.BaseHelper com.hexaview.framework.webtier.controllers.BaseController.baseHelper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'baseHelper': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.hexaview.wealthnewsmate.daotier.services.entityinfo.IEntityInfoDataService com.hexaview.framework.webtier.helpers.BaseHelper.entityInfoDataService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityInfoDataService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.hexaview.wealthnewsmate.daotier.repo.entityinfo.IEntityInfoRepository com.hexaview.wealthnewsmate.daotier.services.entityinfo.EntityInfoDataServiceImpl.entityInfoRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IEntityInfoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.hexaview.wealthnewsmate.daotier.models.core.EntityInfo
```

18:56:43,056 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-4) Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'MyPersistentUnit'
18:56:43,057 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-4) Context initialization failed:  here

Answer (score 0):

There is no entry for `EntityInfo` in the `persistence.xml`. Replace `<class>com.hexaview.wealthnewsmate.daotier.models</class>` with `<class>com.hexaview.wealthnewsmate.daotier.models.core.EntityInfo</class>` in the `persistence.xml`.

Comment: add all entities to `persistence.xml` like this `<class>fullPackageName.className</class>`